# Add sql statement into database

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have to insert a SQL statement as string into database like:

```
string content = "insert into myTable(content) values ('" + myContent + "')";
string sql = "insert into myTable2(sqlStatement) values ('" + content + "')";
```

Obviously this doesnt not work because of `'` inside `content`, so I added the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(content);
content = content.Replace("'", "\\'");
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

I'm sure the variable `content` has been changed, but still have error with `ExecuteNonQuery()`

I have tried the following too, all failed:

```
content = content.Replace("'", "\\\'");
content = content.Replace("'", "\\\\'");
content = content.Replace("'", @"\'");
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to escape single quote in a string, do not use `\` but instead double the quotes. Example, you want to insert `St. Peter's Chapel`, it should be

```
string content = "St. Peter''s Chapel"
```

As a side note, it is not the proper way to do. The correct way is to parameterized the values to avoid from `SQL Injection`.

C# Code Snippet:

```
string content = "St. Peter's Chapel"
string connStr = "connection string here";
string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO tableName (content) VALUES (@content)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // do not hide it
            // e.Message.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

For proper coding

- use `using` statement for propr object disposal
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle objects

Comment: I'd actually get move the quoting part down to the bottom or get rid of it entirely. There's really no reason to use that, and it's worth encouraging the OP to stop embedding values in their SQL *right now*.

Comment: @JonSkeet I totally agree with you. the reason why I add the doubling of single quote is to add user an idea how to properly escape single quote if he wants to directly execute in database management tool.